# How to get all TextRun elements

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Using **Google App Script**, is there a way to get all the *TextRuns* (a block of text with the same format) in **Google Docs**?

I'm trying to create a function that batch replaces one specific text format (from black text to white text).

I've looked through the GAS reference, but can't find anything that does this. `findElement()` doesn't allow the `ElementType TextRun`. And overall *TextRun* doesn't seem to be a functional/manipulable element, at least in the current ref docs -- even though the Document Structure doc does mention it as a sub-element of Paragraph.

So, is there a way to get all the *TextRuns*? Or is there an equivalent alternative?

Comment: `findElement(text)` and check text.getForegroundColor()==="black"?

Comment: Already tried that. findElement(text) will return a block per paragraph, ignoring the formatting within the block. getForegroundColor() would return null when the formatting is not uniform. This is why I was specifically searching for a way to get a TextRun instead of any text block.

Comment: One way would be to loop through  the block for each offset: `.getForegroundColor(offset)`. Another thing to try would be the [api](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#ParagraphElement) through advanced Google services. Sidenote: See [ask]. If you've tried something, you should mention it in your question with your **code** and **documentation links**. It's time efficient.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you change formatting within a google doc for multiple occurrences using findText()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32674241/how-do-you-change-formatting-within-a-google-doc-for-multiple-occurrences-using)

Answer (score 1):

Text runs can be retrieved using [Document.get](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get). The runs are located at Body> Structured Element (Paragraph)>Paragraph Element>[TextRun](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#ParagraphElement) in the document json. [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/docs) may be used to access the api from apps script.