# Make URL Address Text a Clickable URL Using setLinkUrl() With Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, pdf-generation

Happy New Year to Everyone..

I have a list of names and a list of URLs that I will use to generate a PDF document with the contents of each of these data. In the document, I want the URL address to be clickable text.
For single data, this is not a problem, and I managed to create it. I have difficulty when the documents I generate are multiple. The script I made is as follows :

```
 function createPDFDocuments() {
   var sheetDatabase  = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName('DATABASE"');
   var startRow       = 2 ; 
   var rowNo          = sheetDatabase.getLastRow();
   var sumRow         = rowNo - startRow  ;
   var fileMasterID   = DriveApp.getFileById('DOCUMENT ID XXXXX') ;  

// I have a list of Name  in a Spreadsheet, that are in column number 2
   var nameList       = sheetDatabase.getRange(2,2,sumRow,1).getValues() ;

// I have a list of URLs to, in a Spreadsheet that are in column number 8
   var urlDataList    = sheetDatabase.getRange(2,8,sumRow,1).getValues() ;

   for(var i=0;i<nameList.length;i++){ 

   var urlData  = (urlDataList[i][0]) ;
   var name     = (nameList[i][0]) ;

// Copy New Document from Document Master
   var copyId     = DriveApp.getFileById(fileMasterID).makeCopy('DOC FOR : '+name).getId();                      
   var copyDoc    = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
   var copyBody   = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

// The master document has text that will be replaced with data, namely <<TEXT NAME>> 
// to be replaced with the names in the list, and <<TEXT URL ADDRESS>> 
// which will be replaced with the URL in the list

   copyBody.replaceText('<<TEXT NAME>>', name );
   copyBody.replaceText('<<TEXT URL ADDRESS>>', urlData);

// Replace with the text to make a link and the corresponding URL
   var teksUrlData  =  urlData ;

// Find the text, to turn into a link
   var teksRangeUrlData =copyBody.findText(teksUrlData);

// This is where my script failed, when I create a log, it returns null.
   Logger.log("Range URL Data   : "+teksRangeUrlData)

// If text is found, convert it to a link
   if (teksRangeUrlData) {
      var teksElement  = teksRangeUrlData.getElement();
      var teksStart    = teksRangeUrlData.getStartOffset();
      var teksEnd      = teksRangeUrlData.getEndOffsetInclusive();

// Delete the text between the Start text and the End text    
   teksElement.deleteText(teksStart, teksEnd);

// Enter the link with the appropriate text
   teksElement.insertText(teksStart, teksUrlData).setLinkUrl(urlData);
  
    }

   copyDoc.saveAndClose();

// Convert temporary document to PDF by using the getAs blob conversion

   docblob = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf"); 

   docblob.setName("DOC FOR : "+name+".pdf");

   var file        = DriveApp.createFile(docblob);
   var newFileId   = file.getId();   
   var newFile     = DriveApp.getFileById(newFileId);

// Move To Destination Folder 
   var docFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FOLDER TO SAVE DOC ID XXXX")

   newFile.moveTo( docFolder);

//  Dell Temporary FIle
   DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(true);
      }
   }
```

I used [this documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211804/google-apps-script-make-text-a-clickable-url-using-replacetext) too, but it still failed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- I think that Class SpreadsheetApp has no method of `getSheetByName`. So, I think that in your showing script, an error occurs at `var sheetDatabase = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName('DATABASE"');`. But, you say `For single data, this is not a problem, and I managed to create it.`. So, I'm worried that you might have miscopied your current script.
- And, in your script, `DATABASE"` is used as the sheet name. Is that `DATABASE` instead of `DATABASE"`? Please confirm your sheet name again.
- In the case of `sheetDatabase.getRange(2, 2, sumRow, 1)`, the value of the last row is not retrieved.
- I think that the destination folder can be declared outside of the loop.
- The PDF file can be directly created to the folder using the method createFile of Class Folder.

When these points are reflected in a sample script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet. And, please set the variables of `sheetName`, `templateDocumentId`, and `dstFolderId`. **Please confirm your sheet name again.**

```js
function createPDFDocuments() {
  const sheetName = "DATABASE"; // Please set your sheet name.
  const templateDocumentId = "###"; // Please set your template document ID.
  const dstFolderId = "###"; // Please set your destination folder ID.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const [, ...values] = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues().map(r => [r[1], r[7]]);
  const template = DriveApp.getFileById(templateDocumentId);
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(dstFolderId);
  values.forEach(([name, url]) => {
    if (!name || !url) return;
    const copiedTemplate = template.makeCopy('DOC FOR : ' + name);
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copiedTemplate.getId());
    const body = doc.getBody();
    body.replaceText('<<TEXT NAME>>', name);
    const t = "<<TEXT URL ADDRESS>>";
    let s = body.findText(t);
    while (s) {
      const e = s.getElement();
      const start = s.getStartOffset();
      e.asText().replaceText(t, url).asText().setLinkUrl(start, start + url.length - 1, url);
      s = body.findText(t, s);
    }
    doc.saveAndClose();
    folder.createFile(doc.getBlob().setName("DOC FOR : " + name + ".pdf"));
    copiedTemplate.setTrashed(true);
  });
}
```

When this script is run, a template document is copied, and the placeholders `<<TEXT NAME>>` and `<<TEXT URL ADDRESS>>` are replaced using the values retrieved from columns "B" and "H". And, the document is saved as a PDF format to the destination folder. And, the copied template document is removed.

#### Note:

- From your showing script, it supposes that the columns "B" and "H" of `DATABASE` sheet are the values of `name` and `url`, respectively. Please confirm this again.

#### References:

- [Class SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
- [createFile(blob) of Class Folder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createfileblob)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Happy New Year @Tanaike.  Thank you, it's been almost a year and a half for me to learn Script from Zero. You are always responsive in answering, with detailed explanations and even adding references that I can learn from myself. You have helped me a lot when I was stuck trying to learn independently. I wish you good health and success.

Comment: Regarding the correction/ confirmation  you asked about, yes! The name of the sheet that I use is DATABASE, I wasn't careful about marking it when creating the script. And yes, the columns I mean are column 'B" and column "H".

Comment: After I adjusted it to the complete script that I created, the script you suggested worked. Thank you very much. Even though other people are on holiday on January 1, you still care about helping other people solve problems.

Comment: @PSAB Plalangan Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.